# Work Item Linked Queries/Scripts for Reporting in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)

Tags: reporting, azure-devops, powershell-3.0, querying

I wanted to create a report on my VSTS Team Project which has the details of the Work Item Linking relationships in a Team Project. Ex: *Epics→Features→UserStories*. Since there are parent/child relationships between Epics & Features and also between Features & UserStories, I wanted to create a report (.csv or .xls) which has all the details of these workitems and their relationships.

Could someone let me know on what is the best and easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you could check it via project with TFS add-in (included in VS or team explorer).

1. Create a query (Tree of work items) 
   [image]
2. Open Project
3. Click Team=>Choose Team project
4. Click Get Work Items=>Select that query=>Find=>Select All=>OK
   [image]

After that you can check the result in project, you also can collapse parent item by clicking corresponding title.

You can achieve it programmatically by using TFS API with Excel add-in.

1. Create a [document level excel add-in project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f27xe9xb.aspx)
2. Install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)
3. Run query by using [Query.RunLinkQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.query.runlinkquery(v=vs.120).aspx) method.
4. Get test cases in requirement test suites
5. Check test results of these test cases
6. Get associated work item of test result
7. Save data to excel per your detail requirement.

Simple code:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://XX.visualstudio.com"));
            ITestManagementService tms = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
            ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = tms.GetTeamProject("[team project name]");
            WorkItemStore workitemstore = tfsCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            QueryHierarchy queryRoot = workitemstore.Projects["[team project name]"].QueryHierarchy;
            QueryFolder queryFolder = queryRoot["Shared Queries"] as QueryFolder;
            QueryDefinition qd = queryFolder["[query name]"] as QueryDefinition;
            Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            variables.Add("project", "[team project name]");
            Query query = new Query(workitemstore, qd.QueryText, variables);

            var results = query.RunLinkQuery();
            foreach(var lr in results)
            {
                //check relationship according to sourceId, TargetId and LinkTypeId (2: child)
                int parentId = lr.SourceId;
                int currentId = lr.TargetId;
            }

            foreach (ITestPlan p in teamProject.TestPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Plan - {0} : {1}", p.Id, p.Name);

                foreach (var suite in p.RootSuite.SubSuites)
                {
                    IRequirementTestSuite requirementSuite = suite as IRequirementTestSuite;
                    if (requirementSuite != null)
                    {
                        var requirementId = requirementSuite.RequirementId;
                        //check requirementId with user story Id
                        foreach(var tc in requirementSuite.TestCases)
                        {
                            var lastResult = teamProject.TestResults.ByTestId(tc.Id).OrderByDescending(tr => tr.DateStarted).FirstOrDefault();
                            if(lastResult.Outcome== Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Failed)
                            {
                               int[] ids= lastResult.QueryAssociatedWorkItems();
                                foreach(int id in ids)
                                {
                                    var wit = workitemstore.GetWorkItem(id);
                                }

                            }

                        }


                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @starain..Thanks for the information. Can we achieve the same using some kind of scripting/programming tools? I am preferring some scripting since i want to further extend the query to get TestSuites (Requirement based Test suites created using UserStories) and then getting the TestCases linked to those TestSuites. Ex: UserStory→TestSuite→TestCases. So the requirement for my final report is as follows: Epic→Feature→UserStory→TestSuite→TestCases→TestResult→Bug (if the Test Result is "Fail"). Is it possible to get this kind of data into a single report?

Comment: @Srini33 Yes, you can achieve that programmatically by using TFS API, I updated my answer.

Comment: @starain..Thanks for the information. If possible could you please suggest me the best approach to take inorder to learn the TFS API programming since i am new to this.. Also, it would take some time for me to understand the above program. I would let you know if i need some clarification.

Comment: @Srini33 There is a blog that has many samples (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/tag/tfs-api/page/4/).

Comment: @starain..I have some queries: (1)Since the VSTS data is hosted in cloud, could you please let me know the procedure to follow inorder to install the "Microsoft TFS Extended Client package". I have gone through the link that you shared but i am not able to find the Package Manager Console in my VSTS account to run the installation command. So could you please provide a reference for this.(2)Also do we also get the console after the installation of package,on which we can write and execute programs (like your above code).Could you please throw some light on how exactly this entire flow works?

Comment: @Srini33 First, the Package Manager Console is in Visual Studio instead of VSTS(https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/package-manager-console). Secondly, after install that package, the necessary assemblies reference will be included to your project. You can achieve your requirement by using TFS API (included in package) in many application, such as Console Application, Windows form application, excel add-in etc...

Comment: @starain..Thanks for the response and the information. I am somehow finding it a little difficult to follow and understand the TFS related stuff since i am new to this. Could you please let me know whether it is possible to achieve the same above implementation by connecting to VSTS using Powershell and calling the RESTful APIs? If it is possible, could you please provide some reference/guidance to follow inorder to achieve this?

Comment: @Srini33 Yes, it is possible, you can call VSTS REST API by using Invoke-RestMethod PowerShell function (Article: http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/). You also can call VSTS REST API programmatically with TFS extended Client package through PowerShell (Article: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples, PowerShell script is similar to C# code)  On the other hand, creating new threads for detail questions/issues is better for you to solve your issues/questions.

Comment: @starain..Thanks for the suggestion. I would try post a new thread for each detail question from next time.

Comment: @Srini33 Great. If my answer helps you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: @starain..I was not able test the code since i am looking to implement the same using REST APIs. But i understood the logic of the above code. So i am marking it as answer.

Comment: @Srini33 You could open new threads once you have issues/questions. We will help you to solve them.